# Row error set<container> can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'

Tags: flutter, dart

The `if(...) {...} else {...}` condition is not working in `Row` widget.
I have tried wrapping it with a `Container`, that didn't work nor did calling them as a function. I want the if condition to be executed when `widget.sp` is not equal to null. But I am not understanding the error.

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

class Product_Card extends StatefulWidget {
  const Product_Card({Key key, this.imagefile, this.productname,this.productdetails,this.mrp,this.sp,this.currencie,this.quantity,this.unit}) : super(key: key);
  final PickedFile imagefile;
  final String productname;
  final String currencie;
  final String mrp;
  final String sp;
  final String quantity;
  final String unit;
  final String productdetails;




  @override
  _Product_CardState createState() => _Product_CardState();
}

class _Product_CardState extends State<Product_Card> {
  bool addproduct ;
  int _counter=1;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    addproduct = false;
  }

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }
  void _decrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter--;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 150,
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 8, 15, 8),
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      child: Column(
       // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        //crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Row(
           // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[

              SizedBox(
                height: 110,
                width: 100,
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      image: DecorationImage(
                          image: FileImage(
                            File(widget.imagefile.path),
                          ),
                          fit: BoxFit.contain),
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        topLeft: Radius.circular(12),
                        bottomLeft: Radius.circular(12),
                        topRight: Radius.circular(12),
                        bottomRight: Radius.circular(12),
                      )),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 10),
              /*Container(
                height: 120,
                width: 50,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                      image: FileImage(
                        File(imagefile.path),
                      ),
                      fit: BoxFit.fitWidth),
                ),
              ),*/
              Expanded(
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,

                  children: [
                    //productname (),
                    Text(
                      widget.productname ,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 20,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(

                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                      child: Text("${widget.quantity} ${widget.unit}",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 15,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 30,
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width-120,
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                       crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                        children: [
                          if(widget.sp!=null)
                            Container(
                              child: RichText(text: TextSpan(children: [
                                TextSpan(
                                  text: '${widget.currencie}${widget.sp}',
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      color: Colors.black),
                                ),
                                TextSpan(
                                  text: '${widget.currencie}${widget.mrp}',
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                      decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough,
                                      color: Colors.black54),
                                ),
                              ])),
                            )

                          else
                          Text("${widget.currencie}${widget.mrp}" ,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 18,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                            
                          ),
                          Container(child: addproduct?addmore():add())
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget addButton() {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: ()  { },
      child: Center(
        child: Container(
          height: 20,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(


              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4), color: Colors.blueAccent,


          ),
          child: Center(
              child: Text(
                "ADD +",
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16),
              )),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget spprice(){
      RichText(text:
        TextSpan(children: [

        TextSpan(
          text: '${widget.currencie}${widget.sp}',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,color: Colors.black),
        ),
        TextSpan(
          text: '${widget.currencie}${widget.mrp}',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough, color: Colors.black54),
        ),
      ])
      );
  }

  Widget mrpprice(){
    Container(
      child: Text("${widget.currencie}${widget.mrp}" ,
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 18,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,color: Colors.black
        ),
      ),
    );
  }


  Widget add(){
    return Container(
      height: 20,
      child: OutlineButton(
          onPressed: (){

            setState(() {
              addproduct=true;
            });
          },
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue),
          //color: Colors.blueAccent,
          //disabledBorderColor: Colors.blueAccent,
          child: Text("ADD +",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, fontSize: 16,fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
        )
      ),
    );

  }

  Widget productname(){

    Wrap(

      children: [
        Text(
          widget.productname ,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            fontSize: 20,
          ),
        ),

      ],
    );

  }

  Widget addmore(){
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: Radius.circular(4),
          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(4),
          topRight: Radius.circular(4),
          bottomRight: Radius.circular(4),
        ),
      ),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          InkWell(
            onTap: (){
              if(_counter==1) {
                setState(() {
                  addproduct=false;
                });
              }
              else{
                _decrementCounter();
              }
            },
            child: Container(
              height: 18,
              width: 25,

              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(4),
                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(4),
                  ),
                //border: Border.all(color: Colors.blueAccent),

                  shape: BoxShape.rectangle, color: Colors.white
              ),
              child: Center(

                child: Text("-", style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.blueAccent, fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            height: 18,
            width: 25,

            child: Center(
              child: Text("$_counter", style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.blueAccent, fontSize: 16,),),
            ),
          ),
          InkWell(
            onTap: (){
              if(_counter<=99){
              _incrementCounter();
              }
            },
            child: Container(
              height: 18,
              width: 25,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topRight: Radius.circular(4),
                    bottomRight: Radius.circular(4),
                  ),
                  shape: BoxShape.rectangle, color: Colors.white
              ),
              child: Center(
                child: Text("+" , style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.blueAccent, fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );

  }
}
```

[Image result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9E8IS.jpg)

selling price text form field
'''

```
  Widget spTextField() {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: TextFormField(
        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
        inputFormatters: [
          FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp("[0-9\.]")),
          CurrencyFormat()
        ],
        controller: _sp,
        validator: (value) {

          if (value.length > 7) {
            return "Enter less than 1000000";
          }
          return null;
        },
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelText: "Selling Price",
        ),
        maxLines: null,
      ),
    );
  }
```

'''

Comment: Can you share the entire widget? And what is this code doing: `Container(child: addproduct?addmore():add())`. It does not look like something that will compile.

Comment: i have created widgets thats running fine

Comment: i uploaded the entire code @YoBo

Comment: but the if else condition doesn't run properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
In this case to use `if else` you can remove `{}` and `comma` before `else`
In working demo, first widget `sp` is `null` and second widget is string
code snippet

```
  Test(
      sp: null,
      currencie: 1.0,
      mrp: 2.0,
    ),
  Test(
      sp: "string",
      currencie: 1.0,
      mrp: 2.0,
    )
  ...       
  children: [
    if (widget.sp != null)
      Container(
        child: RichText(
          text: TextSpan(
            children: [
              TextSpan(
                text: '${widget.currencie}${widget.sp}',
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 18,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Colors.black),
              ),
              TextSpan(
                text: '${widget.currencie}${widget.mrp}',
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 15,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                    decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough,
                    color: Colors.black54),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      )
    else
      Text(
        "${widget.currencie}${widget.mrp}",
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 18,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        ),
      ),
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Test(
              sp: null,
              currencie: 1.0,
              mrp: 2.0,
            ),
            Test(
              sp: "string",
              currencie: 1.0,
              mrp: 2.0,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  String sp;
  double currencie;
  double mrp;

  Test({this.sp, this.currencie, this.mrp});
  @override
  _TestState createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  bool addproduct = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
      children: [
        if (widget.sp != null)
          Container(
            child: RichText(
              text: TextSpan(
                children: [
                  TextSpan(
                    text: '${widget.currencie}${widget.sp}',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 18,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: Colors.black),
                  ),
                  TextSpan(
                    text: '${widget.currencie}${widget.mrp}',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 15,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                        decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough,
                        color: Colors.black54),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
        else
          Text(
            "${widget.currencie}${widget.mrp}",
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 18,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),

        Container(child: addproduct ? Text("addmore()") : Text("add()"))
        //Container(child: addproduct ? addmore() : add())
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no `if() {...} else {...}` available in the Widget Tree. Instead, use a ternary operation `'sp != null ? Container(...) : Container(...)`

I'm not sure what `Container(child: addproduct ? addmore() : add())` does.

I suppose `addproduct` is a bool flag and both `addmore()` and `add()` return a Widget (probably a button) which is fine.

Add more detail to your question if you need more help.